# What are the prerequisites for remoting into VNet Windows VM using Azure Bastion?

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

Are there any prerequisites (nsg rules / firewall rules) required for RDP'ing into a VNet Windows VM (private IP only) using Azure Bastion?  What ports does it use?  Does it use a P2S VPN IP?

Comment: there are no docs for this service now (nor can ou create it as far as I can tell). so the answer is - who knows

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to open any ports in NSG for your VM in the VNET for Azure Bastion. The traffic flow is as follows:

Client from Portal via HTTPS --> Azure Bastion in the VNET --> Translates HTTPS to RDP session and forwards the traffic to VMs within the same VNET with Private IP. So, from the VM's perspective the traffic will be coming from Azure Bastion Instance IP addresses.

You don't need to make any changes to your environment. You can just add Bastion to your VNET and you can RDP to the VMs without Public IP from portal.

Comment: Azure Bastion is currently in Private Preview. You will not be able to see this resource in the Portal.